# How to make sort slide down window?

Tags: flutter

I try to make something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKa9T.png), or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By7BO.png)

I use

```
IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            PageRouteBuilder(
                opaque: false,
                pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) => MyPopup()));
      },
```

to call for it, but in popup what kind of widget should return and and how to animate its appearance by pushing it from the bottom and closing it using swipe down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bottom sheet from the Material design component which is same as this,

[Guidline or example from Material Design site](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom/sheets-bottom.html#standard-bottom-sheet)
[Also class from official flutter doc.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html)

Example:

```
void _showBottomSheet(){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (builder){
          return new Container(
            height: 350.0,
            color: Colors.transparent, //could change this to Color(0xFF737373),
            child: new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(15.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(15.0))),
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text("Model Sheet Example Demo"),
                )),
          );
        }
    );
  }
```